# Is this article obsolete ? Should I use other aproach of aplication architecture nowadays?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, architecture, javabeans

I was wondering if the next article could be obsolete today. It was written in 2007. Describes MVC Architecture based java beans mimicking properties of the model to the controller. Also uses reflection for each property setted.

Article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html

Code: http://www.multiupload.com/PFSRSU9ELY

1. Should I follow the above article or Would be better to use an object aproach ? keeping the properties into collections within the model and so on...
2. Should I stop trying to make my own architecture for an application and give a try to Spring Framework or any other fw. ?

Comment: Really depends on what you are trying to do. For small projects these frameworks may be overkill, maybe you don't use them and in 2 years time the project is a total mess because you never used one etc. What are you actually trying to do.

Comment: @steve Which framework is that?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn/understand how I can design an skeleton to write small/medium apps. How to decouple the layers, how to make things reusable. Good practices at last. One thing that could help me is to know how others create these architecture's. Packaging, patterns to use maybe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC itself can't be obsoleted; it's a design pattern.

The article specifically targets Swing, which has seen some changes since 2007, but nothing that would specifically negate the article, although perhaps some classes have been changed, tweaked, etc.

There may be easier ways to implement some of the functionality, but it demonstrates one way of using MVC within a Swing app within JSE 6.

Frameworks like [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) (Groovy-based) take the abstraction level a step further, and might be more appropriate for modern desktop app development, but that's more a matter of preference and convenience.

Comment: Yes, of course. MVC Can't. I was aiming on the technologies used. If its nice to make a MVC based on Java Beans. The need to use reflection to decouple Model/Controller messages. This practices could be obsolete or can be done diferent/better nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off reusing some of the solutions existing out there for MVC implementation (e.g. Spring). People coding those frameworks already faced issues you will find if you implement your own solution. I am sure you will learn a lot by implementing your own MVC solution, but that's the only thing you will get from it.